# Is there a tool for generating Persistent entity definitions from an existing database?

Tags: mysql, haskell, haskell-persistent

I understand you can use `persistent-template` to declare entities, but is there a tool for building those from an existing database? Specifically is there a tool that can be pointed at a MySQL database and return definitions that can be used by Persistent?